# Update a element inside object in aobject array with Immutability helper js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability-helper

I need  to add or subtract a value of a element in object array using *Immutability helper*

```
const selectedFood= [
{id: uuidv4(), name: "pizza", price: 1700, amount: 3},
{id: uuidv4(), name: "cheese", price: 600, amount: 10},
{id: uuidv4(), name: "fried rice", price: 500, amount: 4},
{id: uuidv4(), name: "coke", price: 100, amount: 5}]


const [foodArray, setFoodArray] = useState(selectedFood);
```

This code works flawlessly and this is what i want **except the index**

```
setFoodArray((prev) => {
                 return update(prev, {2: {amount: {$apply: function(x) {return x -1}}}})
        })
```

the number 2 here should be the index

so i used this to get the index

```
const index = foodArray.indexOf(foodArray.find((single) => {
            return single.id === id
        }));
```

putting this index variable there dosn't work

```
setFoodArray((prev) => {
                 return update(prev, {index: {amount: {$apply: function(x) {return x -1}}}})
        })
```

[Picture for understanding better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqq9s.png)

can anyone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```js
setFoodArray((prev) => {
    return update(prev, {[index]: {amount: {$apply: function(x) {return x -1}}}})
})
```